# Vncserver with Google cloud instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

So I recently started working with vncserver on Google cloud recently because I had to enable gui to work efficiently using pycharm but when I stop my instance and restart it again the gui stops working (gray screen on vncserver ) log is as follows

`7/05/18 12:47:11 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
07/05/18 12:47:11 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
07/05/18 12:47:11 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
07/05/18 12:47:11 All Rights Reserved.
07/05/18 12:47:11 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
07/05/18 12:47:11 Desktop name 'X' (instance-1:1)
07/05/18 12:47:11 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
07/05/18 12:47:11 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
07/05/18 12:47:11 Listening for HTTP connections on TCP port 5801
07/05/18 12:47:11   URL http://instance-1:5801
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other appli
cations.
gnome-session-binary[8151]: DEBUG(+): Enabling debugging
gnome-session-binary[8151]: DEBUG(+): hardware acceleration check is disabled
gnome-session-binary[8151]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of QT_IM_MODULE=ibus environment va
riable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[8151]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus environment 
variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[8151]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is
-deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[8151]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- environme
nt variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[8151]: DEBUG(+): Using systemd for session tracking
gnome-session-binary[8151]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
gnome-session-binary[8151]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
07/05/18 12:47:18 Got connection from client 39.50.207.178
07/05/18 12:47:19 Using protocol version 3.8
07/05/18 12:47:19 Full-control authentication passed by 39.50.207.178
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
07/05/18 12:47:19 Using zlib encoding for client 39.50.207.178
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
07/05/18 12:47:19 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 39.50.207.178
07/05/18 12:47:19 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
07/05/18 12:47:20 Pixel format for client 39.50.207.178:
07/05/18 12:47:20   8 bpp, depth 6
07/05/18 12:47:20   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
07/05/18 12:47:20 Using raw encoding for client 39.50.207.178
07/05/18 12:47:20 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
"~/.vnc/instance-1:1.log" 63L, 4606C`

`.vnc/xstartup` file is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
autocutsel -fork
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
#unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a forum for server administration but for programming problems. You might find help in one of our sibling sites.

Comment: I have seen several questions like that here already I will post on "sibling sites" too ty for responding